# postfix SSL_accept from amazonaws every 15 seconds

Tags: amazon-web-services, postfix, tls

In my log-file I have get a lot of unsuccessfull connection from an amazon AWS Server. When I say a lot, than I actually mean a lot: About all 10-15 seconds an unsucessfull connect request as you can see.

```
Nov 21 15:53:40 myserver postfix/smtpd[1657]: SSL_accept error from ec2-18-216-14-119.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com[18.216.14.119]: lost connection
Nov 21 15:53:40 myserver postfix/smtpd[1657]: lost connection after CONNECT from ec2-18-216-14-119.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com[18.216.14.119]
Nov 21 15:53:40 myserver postfix/smtpd[1657]: disconnect from ec2-18-216-14-119.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com[18.216.14.119]
Nov 21 15:53:51 myserver postfix/smtpd[1657]: connect from ec2-18-216-14-119.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com[18.216.14.119]
Nov 21 15:54:02 myserver postfix/smtpd[1657]: SSL_accept error from ec2-18-216-14-119.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com[18.216.14.119]: lost connection
Nov 21 15:54:02 myserver postfix/smtpd[1657]: lost connection after CONNECT from ec2-18-216-14-119.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com[18.216.14.119]
Nov 21 15:54:02 myserver postfix/smtpd[1657]: disconnect from ec2-18-216-14-119.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com[18.216.14.119]
Nov 21 15:54:19 myserver postfix/smtpd[1657]: connect from ec2-18-216-14-119.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com[18.216.14.119]
Nov 21 15:54:29 myserver postfix/smtpd[1657]: SSL_accept error from ec2-18-216-14-119.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com[18.216.14.119]: lost connection
Nov 21 15:54:29 myserver postfix/smtpd[1657]: lost connection after CONNECT from ec2-18-216-14-119.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com[18.216.14.119]
Nov 21 15:54:29 myserver postfix/smtpd[1657]: disconnect from ec2-18-216-14-119.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com[18.216.14.119]
```

Now I have checked some other reports on this, and I would not bother if this would just be occassional. But every 10-15 sec from the identical server is quite a lot.

So my question is:Now I have checked some other reports on this, and I would not bother if this would just be occassional. But every 10-15 sec from the identical server, is what really bothers me.

Has someone made a similar experience, an idea how to prevent it, or a explanation.

Comment: Sounds like a monitoring application. What do you have monitoring your server’s uptime and reachability?

Comment: This is just a small VPS, so any monitoring would be on a 1-5 minute intervall. And as far as I have read this is the trial to establish a TLS-connection with fall back to my server. NOthing that I know that should exist.